# Hibernate: Passing a list of data to `SELECT IN ( )` clause generate errors

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, classcastexception

I am trying to generate a `Hibernate Query`. Below is my code

```
public List<Product> getProductsByIDList(List<Product> list, Session session) {
        //Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Product p");
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        //strBuilder.append("(");
        for (Product p : list) {
           strBuilder.append(p.getIdproduct().toString());
           strBuilder.append(",");
        }
        strBuilder.replace(strBuilder.length()-1, strBuilder.length(), "");
        //strBuilder.append(")");
        System.out.println(strBuilder);
        
        Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Product p \n"
                + "join fetch p.sparePart sp\n"
                + "join fetch p.vehicleModel v\n"
                + "WHERE p.idproduct IN ( :plist )");
        query.setParameter("plist", strBuilder);
        List<Product> finalList = (List<Product>) query.list();
        return finalList;
    }
```

The `StringBuilder` generates the following output which is what i need.

```
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
```

When my code is executed, it generates the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at dao.product.ProductDAOImpl.getProductsByIDList(ProductDAOImpl.java:52)
    at service.ProductService.getProductsByIDList(ProductService.java:61)
    at rest.ProductJSONService.getProductsByIDList(ProductJSONService.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

But If i manually executed the code like this, it works fine.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Product p \n"
                + "join fetch p.sparePart sp\n"
                + "join fetch p.vehicleModel v\n"
                + "WHERE p.idproduct IN ( 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49 )");
```

What is wring here?

Comment: Translate your list of products into a list of ids. Pass that list of ids instead of a concatted String.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I should pass a `Collection` and should use `query.setParameterList`. Below is the correct code.

```
@Override
    public List<Product> getProductsByIDList(List<Product> list, Session session) {
        List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Product p : list) {
           idList.add(p.getIdproduct());
        }
        
        Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Product p \n"
                + "join fetch p.sparePart sp\n"
                + "join fetch p.vehicleModel v\n"
                + "WHERE p.idproduct IN (:plist)");
        query.setParameterList("plist", idList);
        List<Product> finalList = (List<Product>) query.list();
        return finalList;
    }
```

Comment: We have streams now, do something like `list.stream().map(Product::getIdproduct).collect(Collectors.toList());` to achieve the same a bit easier. But both will work.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Appreciate your comment, good for the knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

Hello I don't know hibernate but this message is clear java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer
Meaning Can not convert string into integer.
Check if you're sending the right type of value